# extracting single frame from MediaElemet or FFmpegInterop

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, windows-phone-8.1, mediaelement

I am writing app (Windows Phone 8.1 Store App) that allows user to connect to IP Camera. I am using [FFmpeg Interop](https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop) library for ffmpeg which allows me to play eg. rtsp streams in media element. I need now a way to somehow extract a single frame from stream or from media element.

I have tested other application wchih allows connecting to IP cameras - IP Centcom, and they have working snapshots only for mjpeg streams as far as I now (they were not working for rtsp). Becouse of that I belive that it is impossible or at very least very hard to export frame from media element.

I have different question - if anyone has ever used FFmpeg Interop and would like to help/explain me how could I modify/extend FFmpegInteropMSS to add method called 'GetThumbnailForStream' that would work similary to 'GetMediaStreamSource' but would return single frame (bitmap or jpg) instead of MediaStreamSource?

Every help would be appreciated

EDIT:

I have found something;

in MediaSampleProvider in method WriteAVPacketToStream (line ~123) there is line

```
auto aBuffer = ref new Platform::Array<uint8_t>(avPacket->data, avPacket->size);
```

and I belive that this is the place that stores single frame data that is needed to convert into bitmap - now since I do not know c++ too much I have a question : how can I convert it into a form that I could return via public method ?

When returning:

```
Platform::Array<uint8_t>^
```

I get

> > 'FFmpegInterop::MediaSampleProvider' : a non-value type cannot have any public data members

EDIT2:

Ok I am doing approprate projection to byte according to [this microsoft information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230301.aspx#PassingToManaged), now I need to check if this is correct data.